# Sharepoint 2010 list Multiple line of text field not showing up in SSRS 2012

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm working on a report using s SharePoint 2010 list as a data source.

Its all good but a field with a multiple line of text(But marked as plain text) doesn't show up in the field list at all.
When i run the query designer ti doesn't show up and i have tried to add it manually

Any ideas what i need to do to fix this?

Cheers in advance